# Copy multiple files from one directory to another from Linux shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to copy several files from one folder to another.  How do I do it from the shell command prompt?

Consider that `folder1` contains ten files (e.g. `file1`, `file2`, `abc`, `xyz`,
 etc.).  I am currently doing the following in order to copy two files from one folder to another:

```
cp /home/ankur/folder/file1 /home/ankur/folder/file2 /home/ankur/dest
```

Typing the full path into the command line for both the files is annoying.
What comes to my mind is regex, but I don't quite know how to do it.

Any help will reduce my RSI ;-)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I guess you are looking for brace expansion:

```
cp /home/ankur/folder/{file1,file2} /home/ankur/dest
```

take a look here, it would be helpful for you if you want to handle multiple files once :

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html

#### tab completion with zsh...

[image]

Comment: Oh this works like a charm :) but i am itching to get more out of it, is there any way where its possible to use tab to get suggestions? :) I know its asking too much but just in case if possible.

Comment: This isn't a glob; it's a brace expansion that expands to two specific file names.

Comment: @chepner you are right, I guess OP doesn't want to cp only `file1 file2` maybe `file_?.t*`... I would correct it.

Comment: +1 for the animation! :D

Comment: @AnkurTank I didn't do much configuration with my bash, I don't think bash supports it out of box. I use zsh as default shell, with my config, it supports `<tab> completion`, add a gif.

Comment: @hek2mgl thx, but it isn't bash...

Comment: @Kent However, it is content that *needs* to get up-voted!

Comment: @hek2mgl in future I would post any answer with a gif! :-D

Comment: I need to double-check my `zsh` settings; currently when I hit tab inside `{`, the full brace expansion expands to two (partial) paths, rather than completing the current path component and leaving the brace expression intact.

Comment: @Kent thanks for adding gif :) but is there tab completion in that situation for bash ?

Comment: @AnkurTank There could be something for bash, however I didn't go any further, since I am satisfied with my zsh. you can do a google.

Comment: Thank you for the link !! I was wondering why it didn't work, turns out space inside the globbing doesn't work (ie `{file1,file2,file3}` will work where `{file1, file2, file3}` was not evaluated correctly

Answer (score 29):

Use wildcards:

```
cp /home/ankur/folder/* /home/ankur/dest
```

If you don't want to copy all the files, you can use braces to select files:

```
cp /home/ankur/folder/{file{1,2},xyz,abc} /home/ankur/dest
```

This will copy `file1`, `file2`, `xyz`, and `abc`.

You should read the sections of the `bash` man page on [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) and [Pathname Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion) for all the ways you can simplify this.

Another thing you can do is `cd /home/ankur/folder`. Then you can type just the filenames rather than the full pathnames, and you can use filename completion by typing <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: I can't because i don't want to copy all the files :(

Comment: +1 However, it won't work with hidden files.

Comment: i would have done `cp -a /home/ankur/folder/* /home/ankur/dest` to copy hidden folders, files, symbolic links but i want to copy files selectively. :-)

Comment: How can an option argument make it copy hidden files and folders? It's the wildcard expansion that skips them, not the `cp` command.

Comment: The `-a` option has nothing to do with hidden files, it's for copying all the file properties.

Comment: Make the pattern more selective: `/home/ankur/folder/file*` would seem to match the files you want to copy.

Comment: @Barmar `has nothing to do`... this is not fully true. `-a` indeed copies ALL files. But it has nothing to do with the `*` glob expansion, you are right. It is hard to explain the difference with my poor English

Comment: I've added an example of using braces to select more specific files.

Comment: @hek2mgl The man page says that `-a` is the same as `-dR --preserve=all`. It will copy everything in subdirectories because of recursion, but not in the the top-level directory because the wildcard won't match the dot-files.

Comment: `-a` (whose definition varies between implementations of `cp`) usually implies `-R`, which performs a recursive copy. As such, it will include hidden files in subdirectories, but would not include hidden files in the current directory not explicitly matched by one of the command-line arguments.

Comment: my mistake i meant `cp -a /home/ankur/folder/ /home/ankur/dest` sorry for confusion.

Comment: But since you said you don't want to copy everything, just selected files, none of that matters.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) in bash:

```
cp /home/ankur/folder/{file1,abc,xyz} /path/to/target
```

Comment: you could reduce this even more.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, but the files in the question aren't named file1, file2, etc... Check my update

Answer (score 4):

Try this simpler one,

```
cp /home/ankur/folder/file{1,2} /home/ankur/dest
```

If you want to copy all the 10 files then run this command,

```
 cp ~/Desktop/{xyz,file{1,2},next,files,which,are,not,similer} foo-bar
```